# check if service is running

Tags: android

I want to check if service is running or not after the application is force closed by user. How can I do this.
          I am doin this in onReceive of broadcastReceiver. But even after force closing it shows service running Toast.

```
   boolean isServiceRunning = AppSettings.getServiceRunning(context);       
    if (isServiceRunning)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,"service running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } 
    else 
    {   
        Toast.makeText(context,"service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    }
```

Comment: how are you doing in onReceive of broadcastReceiver ? Any relevant code will be helpful.

Comment: I have posted the code. What exactly do I need to post

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public boolean checkRunningService() {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo myService : activityManager
                .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if ("com.main.YOUR_SERVICE_NAME".equals(myService.service
                    .getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:-**

Your service in manifest file should be like this:

```
<service
            android:name="com.main.YOUR_SERVICE_NAME"
            android:enabled="true" />
```

Comment: what is the parameter in getSystemServices().I mean is it my service to b checked

Comment: It is android.content.Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE which is used to retrieve ActivityManager.

Comment: Sory for silly questions.

Comment: but its showing error. Create constant ACTIVITY_SERVICE

Comment: do I have to register this alarmManager in manifest file.